# why is Insertion sort best case big O complexity O(n)?

Tags: c++, sorting, complexity-theory, big-o, insertion-sort

Following is my insertion sort code:

```
void InsertionSort(vector<int> & ioList)
{
  int n = ioList.size();
  for (int i = 1 ; i < n ; ++i)
  {
    for (int j = 0 ; j <= i ; ++j)
    {
      //Shift elements if needed(insert at correct loc)
      if (ioList[j] > ioList[i]) 
      {
        int temp = ioList[j];
        ioList[j] = ioList[i];
        ioList[i] = temp;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The average complexity of the algorithm is O(n^2).

From my understanding of big O notation, this is because we run two loops in this case(outer one n-1 times and inner one 1,2,...n-1 = n(n-1)/2 times and thus the resulting asymptomatic complexity of the algorithm is O(n^2).

Now I have read that best case is the case when the input array is already sorted.
And the big O complexity of the algorithm is O(n) in such a case. But I fail to understand how this is possible as in both cases (average and best case) we have to run the loops the same number of times and have to compare the elements. The only thing that is avoided is the  shifting of elements.

So does complexity calculation also involve a component of this swapping operation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this is because your implementation is incorrect. The inner loop should count backward from `i-1` down to `0`, and it should terminate as soon as it finds an element `ioList[j]` that is already smaller than `ioList[i]`.

It is because of that termination criterion that the algorithm performs in O(n) time in the best case:

If the input list is already sorted, the inner loop will terminate immediately for any `i`, i.e. the number of computational steps performed ends up being proportional to the number of times the outer loop is performed, i.e. O(n).

Comment: I thought...In the inner loop to find the correct position for the ioList[i] the element we would have to compare all elements from ioList[o] till ioList[j] (where j <= i-1)...I don't understand, how without comparing all the elements before the ith element, we can find the correct position for ith element ?

Comment: That's because at the time when you deal with the ith element, you have already dealt with i-1, i-2 etc. in the outer loop. You need to realise that in the very first round (i==0), the inner loop has nothing to do at all, in the second round it does one element, in the third round it does two, but one of the two has already been processed in the previous round, and so on. Therefore, at any step of the outer loop, going backward in the inner loop means entering into an area that has been processed before and is guaranteed to be sorted.

Comment: Still unclear...consider this unsorted list 3, 55, 7, 1, 2, 60...
In the 1st pass I consider 55, since 55 is larger than 3, I do nothing..next pass I consider 7... 7 is less than 55, so I swap...
next pass I consider 1...1 is less than all the elements before it...(this i will know only after comparing with all the previous elements)... so i swap it till 1 is the 0th element...and so on...so In each iteration we have to compare all the elements before a particular element...that's what i thought atleast...

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Remember that the O(n) bound _only_ applies in the _best case_, which is when the input list is already sorted. The input list of your example isn't sorted.

Comment: I think what you said is correct.. to find the position, i should skip out of the loop as soon as i find a bigger element than the current element...My inner loop manages the shifting as well...which is why it has to iterate the way it is doing currently...

Answer (score 7):

Your implementation of "insertion sort" is poor.

In your inner loop, you should not scan all the way up to `i-1` swapping each element greater than `ioList[i]`. Instead, you should scan backwards from `i-1` until you find the correct place to insert the new element (that is, until you find an element less than or equal to the new element), and insert it there. If the input is already sorted, then the correct insertion point is always found immediately, and so the inner loop does not execute `i-1` times, it only executes once.

Your sort is also worse than insertion sort on average, since you *always* do `i+1` operations for each iteration of the outer loop -- some of those ops are just a comparison, and some are a comparison followed by a swap. An insertion sort only needs to do on average half that, since for random/average input, the correct insertion point is half way through the initial sorted segment. It's also possible to avoid swaps, so that each operation is a comparison plus a copy.